# Bounding $e^{-az^2}$ along a circular arc segment

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\Re(a) >0$, the following is true:

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} dz \ e^{-az^2} = 0$$

where $C_R$ is an arc fragment of radius $R$ from $-\theta$ to $2 \pi$ and $\theta = 1/2 \arg(a)$. Clearly this integral vanishes but I can't seem to rigorously show it. Would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Is the exponential meant to be inside the integral sign? Also could you be more clear about what $C_R$ is?

Comment: If $a\in\mathbb C$?  If not, what is the point of $\theta=1/2\arg(a)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited the question. $C_R$ is a circle fragment in the fourth quadrant, from $-\theta$ to $2\pi$, with positive orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Call $z = R\cos t + i R\sin t$, for $\theta < t < 0$. Evaluate it in the integral, you are going to end up with a couple of terms of the form $R e^{-aR^2}$ which are going to vanish for large $R$. There is also another term that goes as $R^{-1}{\rm erf}{R}$ that will vanish as well.

Comment: From the line $\theta=1/2\arg(a)$, I think we have $a\in\mathbb C$

Comment: Edited the question a bit